# How to use strange characters in a query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, query-string

I am using silverlight / ASP .NET and C#. What if I want to do this from silverlight for instance,

```
// I have left out the quotes to show you literally what the characters
// are that I want to use
string password = vtakyoj#"5
string encodedPassword = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encryptedPassword, Encoding.UTF8);
// encoded password now = vtakyoj%23%225

URI uri = new URI("http://www.url.com/page.aspx@password=vtakyoj%23%225");

HttpPage.Window.Navigate(uri);
```

If I debug and look at the value of uri it shows up as this (we are still inside the silverlight app),

```
http://www.url.com?password=vtakyoj%23"5
```

So the %22 has become a quote for some reason.

If I then debug inside the page.aspx code (which of course is ASP .NET) the value of Request["password"] is actually this,

```
vtakyoj#"5
```

Which is the original value. How does that work? I would have thought that I would have to go,

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request["password"], Encoding.UTF8)
```

To get the original value.

Hope this makes sense?

Thanks.

Comment: If you bear with me I will try and get the sequence a bit clearer

Comment: *Why* do you want to put a password in a querystring?

Comment: It is an encrypted password. I am passing a password between a silverlight application and an ASP .NET application. It's a long story. It is also using https. Overall it is just to get a commercial application working, and some other changes will need to made in the future to remove this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets start with the UTF8 business.  Esentially in this case there isn't any.  When a string contains characters with in the standard ASCII character range (as your password does) a UTF8 encoding of that string is identical to a single byte ASCII string.

You start with this:-

> vtakyoj#"5

The `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` somewhat aggressively encodes it to:-

> vtakyoj%23%225

Its encoded the # and " however only # has special meaning in a URL. Hence when you view string value of the Uri object in Silverlight you see:-

> vtakyoj%23"5

**Edit** (answering supplementary questions)

> How does it know to decode it?

All data in a url **must** be properly encoded thats part of its being valid Url.  Hence the webserver can rightly assume that all data in the query string has been appropriately encoded.

> What if I had a real string which had %23 in it?

The correct encoding for "%23" would be "%3723" where %37 is %

> Is that a documented feature of Request["Password"] that it decodes it?

Well I dunno, you'd have check the documentation I guess.  BTW use `Request.QueryString["Password"]` the presence of this same indexer directly on `Request` was for the convenience of porting classic ASP to .NET.  It doesn't make any real difference but its better for clarity since its easier to make the distinction between `QueryString` values and `Form` values.

> if I don't use UFT8 the characters are being filtered out.

Aare you sure that non-ASCII characters may be present in the password?  Can you provide an example you current example does not need encoding with UTF-8?

Comment: It turns out that it is not causing a problem as such, but I just want to know that what I am seeing is OK. In the ASP .NET application if I look at the value of Request["password"] I get vtakyoj#"5. I would expect to get vtakyoj%23%225 and then have to call HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request["password"], Encoding.UTF8); to get the original value back. What am I actually seeing here? Does Request["Password"] automatically decode it?

Comment: @peter: Yes it is decoding for you.

Comment: How does it know to decode it? What if I had a real string which had %23 in it? Does it just decode it anyway? That would be annoying. Is that a documented feature of Request["Password"] that it decodes it? I am dealing with something here which I thought was an issue / error, but it is fine actually. Everything is good, and working as expected.

Comment: Also you as saying this 'First lets start with the UTF8 business. Esentially in this case there isn't any'. But if I don't use UFT8 the characters are being filtered out. But I think what you are saying is that the fact that HttpUtility.UrlEncode is aggressive is what is making it work for me.

Comment: I just need to be 100% sure of what is going on here, or else it will bite me in the bum.

Comment: @peter: Answers to your other questions added to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, but ... The example I give is the one that fails if I don't encode to UTF8. If the characters # and " are part of the query string they end up not present in the ASP. NET application.

Comment: Something along the lines filters those characters out, and I guess it doesn't matter if those characters need encoding as UTF8 or not.

Answer (score 0):

If `Request["password"]` is to work, you need `"http://url.com?password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("abc%$^#@")`. I.e. you need ? to separate the hostname.

Also the @ syntax is `username:password@hostname`, but it has been disabled in IE7 and above IIRC.

Comment: Right. I made a mistake. It has nothing to do with @. I have totally changed the question